# Phonegap Cordova browser history

Tags: cordova, browser, browser-history

How can I Access the Browser History on the Device using Phonegap / Cordova ?
My goal is to get a list of pages/websites visited in the device.

Answer (score 1):

When you install a app using phonegap you no can't see all the browser history of the device. You only can access the app history using

```
history.go(-1);
```

But you can't see the history of others apps. Chrome can't see the firefox history or Opera mini history. Can import, and when you import the history, can see.

In the lows versions of phonegap exist (2.1)

```
<preference name="useBrowserHistory" value="true" />
```

I don't know if now exist of it's deprecated.